# Excel to PDF conversion using spire library

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I am trying to convert excel data into pdf using spirepdf library, but the contents of excel(specially if border is there in excel) is overlapping with the footer page number, I tried to update the width of footer but still issue is same. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Spire.XLS library allows converting excel to pdf however the Spire.PDF library does not. Can you confirm which library you were using? If it's Spire.XLS, then you can try to set the height of the PDF page like below code.

```
       Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
       workbook.LoadFromFile("D:\\test.xlsx");

       PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
       pdfDocument.PageSettings.Orientation = PdfPageOrientation.Landscape;
       pdfDocument.PageSettings.Width = 970;
       pdfDocument.PageSettings.Height = 850;

       PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter(workbook);
       PdfConverterSettings settings = new PdfConverterSettings();
       settings.TemplateDocument = pdfDocument;
       pdfDocument = pdfConverter.Convert(settings);

       pdfDocument.SaveToFile("sample.pdf");
```

You can check the [Excel to PDF in C#, VB.NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Convert-Excel-to-PDF-Excel-to-PDF-in-C-VB.NET.html) article for detailed information.
Hope I understood your intention correctly.